# Java SWT: Difference between redraw, reskin, update and requestLayout (and pack)

Tags: java, layout, controls, swt, drawing

Can anybody please explain to me the difference of the methods `Control.redraw()`, `Control.update()`, `Widget.reskin()`, `Control.requestLayout()` and `Control.pack()`?
Unfortunately the API documentation does not tell so much about the differences.

I guess the following:

`Control.requestLayout()` means calculating the size and position of a control inside a Composite when its content (like a text in a label or text field) has changed and perhaps its displayed size/position is not anymore appropriate.
I think I understand `Control.pack()`: It is just a part of `Control.requestLayout` or rather `Composite.layout()` as only the size of controls will be changed but not the position.

`Control.redraw()` and `Control.update()`: It seems to me that both methods just paint the control again and you call them when the operating system does not show it correctly anymore. You call the methods if size and position have not changed. The difference between both methods is that `update()` repaints the control immediately whereas `redraw()` can do it after some time.

I don't understand when I need to call `Widget.reskin()`. It seems to me the same as `Control.redraw()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redraw` requests that the control should be redrawn the next time the event loop runs. Most of the time redraws are managed automatically, calling `redraw` explicitly is rare - usually if you are writing your own control extending `Canvas`.

`update` requests the control is redrawn immediately - used when drawing things like a "rubber band" tracking a mouse drag.

`reskin` is intended for the Eclipse RCP CSS support, it isn't something you would normally call.

`requestLayout` just requests that the `layout` method be called as soon as possible. This may be faster that calling `layout` directly.

`pack` is equivalent to:

```
setSize(computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, changed));
```

It just sets the control to the computed size.

The Eclipse [SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/) site also has lots of example and article.

Comment: Thanks. I had to call redraw() on a Table. Reason: There was a main shell and on top a modal shell where the user determined a new value for the Table in the main shell. When the user confirmed the new value, the modal shell disappeared and I added the new value to the Table as new line. The new line appeared visually empty. Only when the user hovered the mouse pointer on it or set keyboard focus there, the value appeared. But calling redraw() on the Table let the value appear immediately.

Comment: I always use the JFace `TableViewer` for tables, so I'm not sure if redraw is needed on a plain Table or not.